# OfficeJS word-addin - how to remove deleted text/paragraph from document.paragraphs if track changes is on and all revisions inline

Tags: office365, office-js, add-in, office-addins, word-addins

I am working on word add-in and I have the following scenario:

When track changes is on and the changes are displayed inline
[image]

then moved some text/paragraph to another place
[image]

at this point the document added the moved paragraph successfully to its items but it does not remove the deleted paragraph, so we have this paragraph twice.

```
Word.run(context => {
    const { paragraphs } = context.document.body;
    console.log(paragraphs.items) // moved paragraph now in items[2] & items[8]
})
```

So it there a way to delete the deleted paragraph/text from paragraphs.items if they are deleted? or any workaround?
I know there is no way to access track changes in officeJs word ATM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with the API. The problem will be solved when track changes is supported. Particularly to know that track changes is on, ability to turn it on/off or change the mode.